# Keep folders while converting jar to dex

Tags: android, jar, dx

I want to convert my jar to dex: `dx --dex --output=file.dex file.jar`. In `file.jar` exists folder `cnf/` which contains configuration files needed for my classes. But there is no folder `cnf/` in resulting dex-file.

How to keep all files and folders in dex-file while converting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `cnf/` in APK file. APK is a ZIP archive. After unpacking on device `cnf/` folder would be in classpath so it should work the same as inside JAR.

1. After a build remove MANIFEST.MF and certificates from META-INF folder inside APK;

   ```sh
   zip -d file.apk "META-INF/*"
   ```
2. Add your resources (`cnf/`) to APK;

   ```sh
   aapt add -v file.apk cnf/*
   ```
3. Re-sign APK. Here's an example using the default debug key:

   ```sh
   jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore file.apk androiddebugkey
   ```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible, there's no way to store arbitrary files in a dex file. The closest you can get would be to create an "android" jar file, with the dex file as a classes.dex entry, along with anything else you want to put in it, such as the cnf folder.